# Вывод string массива в фаил с <name.type>

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Необходимо создать файл с названием filename (Пользователь вводит сам) и расширение у него должно быть всегда .ahk
 **1. Что писать в file.open() ?**

ufilename = filename + ".ahk"

```
void file_out(int quality, string mass[], string ufilename)  
{  
ofstream file;  
file.open();  

file << "Delete::" << endl;  
for (int i = 1; i <= quality; i++)  
    {  
    file << mass[i] << "{Enter}" << endl;  
    file << "sleep, 0.1" << endl;  
    }  
file << "return" << endl;  

file.close();
}
```

Comment: `ofstream file("random_name.ahk");`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor
А возможно как-то создать файл с именем filename ?

Если использовать ваш вариант , то программа всегда будет создавать файл с названием random_name.ahk  , если он создан ,то дополнять или перезаписывать.

Comment: `ofstream file(ufilename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out);` с С++11 можно просто `ofstream file(ufilename, ios::in | ios::out);`